# Why is the dollar sign used to abbreviate the description of a cache?

Tags: history

What's the historical significance of abbreviating say, an L1 cache as L1$?

Comment: Cash? 10 more to go...

Comment: Oh good lord, is it that obvious?

Comment: Typical face-palm question.  Don't feel bad, I was complaining to a coworker the other day that I wished there was some way I could copy and paste from my computer to paper... the response was one word "Printer"... *sigh*

Comment: I had no idea that was why . . . Allow me to make that facepalm a double.

Comment: I'm ambivalent about closing this: it's pretty basic, but not exactly obvious if you're not familiar with the word "cash". Quickly Googling didn't turn up any results that made this connection obvious, at least. Made the answer community wiki so if someone in the future has the same question, at least there's an answer floating around on the internet.

Comment: It's not even necessarily obvious if you know the word. When I see "$" I think "dollar" (or lately, "jQuery"), but not cash.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suppose that's not obvious for non-native speakers, but as mentioned in the comments, the dollar sign is representative of money, synonymous with the word "cash", which is a homophone for "cache".